# class to read http pages with reliable timout that return `java.io.InputStream`

Tags: java, http, inputstream, urlconnection

Is there any class for reading http pages that return a `java.io.InputStream` and its timeout be reliable?
I tried `java.net.URLConnection` and it doesn't have a reliable timeout (it takes more time that it set to timeout reach)? My Code is here:

```
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(2000);
        con.setReadTimeout(2000);
        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 2):

I expect that the reason that the timeout is not working for you is that you are setting the timeout after the connection has been established, or you are using the wrong setter.  It is also possible that you are using "non-standard" version of URLConnection ...

> *"Some non-standard implementation of this method ignores the specified timeout. To see the read timeout set, please call `getReadTimeout()`."* (or `getConnectTimeout()`)

If you posted the relevant part of your actual code we could give you a better answer ...

---

Alternatively, use the Apache HttpClient library.

Comment: Hi,I'm using Sun's version and I'm setting timeouts using `setConnectTimeout` & `setReadTimeout` methods after creating URLConnection object from a URL object's `openConnection()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache HttpClient to read http pages, it also has an http parser.check this for further [reference about httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html). you can get an InputStream object using their API like this.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

 // Prepare a request object
 HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.apache.org/");

 // Execute the request
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

 // Examine the response status
 System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

 // Get hold of the response entity
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

 // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
 // to worry about connection release
 if (entity != null) {
     InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
```

and coming to timeout part, it totally depends on the network and you cant do much about it from your java code.